# React Native Text Components: How to combine a url and other strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a url format like `http://abc.go.com` or `http://abc.go.com`.

In React Native, i have a `<Text>...</Text>` to contain some child `<Text>...</Text>`

My structure is below :

```
<Text>
    <Text>
      My homepage is a link like : 
    </Text>
    <Text>
      http://abc.go.com
    </Text>
    <Text>
      Welcome Welcome
    </Text>
</Text>
```

In small size Device to check, it shows the below result :

```
My homepage is a link like : http://
abc.go.com Welcome Welcome
```

this result is not my want. (If one line is not enough to show url) I want the result should be:

```
My homepage is a link like : 
http://abc.go.com Welcome Welcome
```

My question is how to combine of a whole url with 'http://' prefix with other strings?

My environment is React Native, JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be the following

```
<Text>
    <Text style={{flex:1}}>
        My homepage is a link like : 
    </Text>
    <Text>
        http://abc.go.com
    </Text>
    <Text>
       Welcome Welcome
     </Text>
</Text>
```

But this would make

> My homepage is a link like:

always take up a whole line on screen which might not suite all use cases if you would give a bit more detailed description I could think of a more universal solution.

Comment: thanks, but your suggestion is the same of above the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a line break by inserting the newline character at the position where you don't want another text to appear.

```
<Text>
  <Text>
    `My homepage is a link like :{'\r\n'}`
  </Text>
  <Text>
    http://abc.go.com
  </Text>
  <Text>
    Welcome Welcome
  </Text>
</Text>
```

P.S. I could not entirely reproduce your error. In my case the separate inner `Text` components were all in a separate line.

Comment: i get your meaning, if my first Text Tag text just a one or two words, my secod Text Tag not in same line, i want dynamic for this case.

Comment: @tommychoo I could not yet reproduce your error. For this we nee more information: Does the problem occur on Android or iOS or both? On which device screen size does the error occur? Which version of react native do you use?

Comment: My version is "react": "^0.14.8" and "react-native": "^0.25.1",
Some small device on iOS or android should occur this problem such as iphone 4-5s size,  i found this image about this case [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mjk5y4y8wzkw30/sample.png?dl=0)